# Inequality on a sub-triplet of a n-variable sequence.

Tags: inequality

The following is motivated by an inequality I came across recently. Let $n\ge 9$ be an integer and $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be positive real numbers such that $\sum a_i = 3$ and $\sum a_i^2 = 1$. It turns out that some of the $a_i$'s have to be fairly large, i.e. $\exists j$ such that $a_j \ge 1/3$. This is easy to see since

$$0 = \sum a_i\left(a_i - \frac{1}{3}\right)$$

and, thus, at least one of the terms in the sum needs to be positive. However, I believe it is also true that there are indices $i<j<k$ such that:

$$a_i + a_j + a_k \ge 1.$$

I think that was the statement of the original inequality that I saw (I saw it on another website and the post had a bunch of typos), but more importantly, numerical simulations seem to confirm it (although it is possible my simulations miss the cases where the inequality fails).

So, any ideas of how to prove this inequality?